# Preserving XML Formatting in XML Attributes in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am just loading xml file and saving it to a new file. This modifies the format of the attributes and adds an extra space from `value="foo"/>` to `value="foo" />`

I know `PreserveWhitespace` doesn't support formatting attributes.

Is there any way I can avoid these spaces/formatting occurring in the end of the XML line?

**Powershell script**

```
$filePath = "C:\BeforeSave.xml"
[xml]$apptypexml = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$apptypexml.PreserveWhitespace = $true
[xml] $apptypexml = [xml] (Get-Content  $filePath)
$apptypexml.Save("C:\AfterSave.xml")
```

**Sample XML Before Saving**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ApplicationTypes>
<executable>
<Item type="registry" value="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\"/> 
<Item type="string" value="\Sample.exe"/> 
</executable>
</ApplicationTypes>
```

**Output XML After Saving**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ApplicationTypes>
<executable>
<Item type="registry" value="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\ "/> <!-- Powershell is giving spaces in the end of attributes -->
<Item type="string" value="\Sample.exe" /> <!-- Powershell is giving spaces in the end of attributes -->
</executable>
</ApplicationTypes>
```

Comment: _...why_ do you feel the need to do this?

Comment: The XML from PS is valid XML. If the application using that XML doesn't accept it then you've got other issues!

Comment: maybe this one will help: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sergey_babkins_blog/2016/12/31/how-to-pretty-print-xml-in-powershell-and-text-pipelines

Comment: @guiwhatsthat your link has a stray `]` at the end so doesn't load.

Comment: @JamesC. Thanks, corrected it

Comment: @JamesC. Yeah its a valid xml and the other application got issues in handling this. Since the application is old legacy codes, I can't touch it. I need to fix this in powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Hacky solution would be a simple text replace:

```
(Get-Content -Path "C:\AfterSave.xml") -replace '" />','"/>' -replace ' "/>','"/>' | Set-Content "C:\AfterSave.xml"
```